# Java exception handling (4 in 1)

Tags: java, exception

If I have exception handling part in my code, and it can fire 4 sqlException, what whould be the best way to handle them which tells the most about what happend and where ?
I made a poor man solution (by using 'exceptionDesc').

Is there any good practice to handle this situation ? (Without making unique class and subclasses )

```
    try {
        exceptionDesc = "prepareStatement"; 
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

        exceptionDesc = "statement.set...";
        statement.setDate(1, sqlDate);

        exceptionDesc = "executeUpdate";
        statement.executeUpdate();

        exceptionDesc = "commit";           
        connection.commit();
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
        if (exceptionDesc.equals("prepareStatement")) {
            LOG.error ...
        } else if (exceptionDesc.equals("executeQuery")) {
            LOG.error(" executeQuery ...
                    ...
                    ...
        throw new SQLException(sqlEx);
    }
```

Comment: If you need four different responses, then write four separate try/catch statements.

Comment: Unique classes and subclasses is the standard way to do this; why are you averse to this option?

Comment: templatetypedef : i just was interested in another way, making unique classes for dao and business layers seems to me too much. I find the way where exceptions of dao layer tells enough to business layer. I forgot to mention the final goal ... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do anything. The stack trace of the exception does that for you:

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    LOG.error("A SQLException happened", e);
    throw e;
}
```

is sufficient. The logger, if configured to show stack traces (which it should do), will print the stack trace and the stack trace will tell exactly which method, at which line, threw the exception. It will also tell which method called the method causing the exception, etc. until the bottom of the stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and what if I would like to use this exception information in my business layer ? is not useful if i well informed ? (I forgot to mention, the second goal would be informing my business layer)

Comment: Your business layer shouldn't have to care whether if it's the prepareStatement call or the executeUpdate call that caused the exception. It shouldn't even have to care whether the DAO uses JDBC or something else. All it cares about is: did the data access operation succeed or not.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You should align the **try catch from** the **most Specific exception** to the **most Abstract exception.**

**2.** But then even if you use the SQLException, the stack trace gonna tell you the following:

**-** The **method name** where the exception occured.

**-** The **class name** where the exception occured.

**-** The **file name** where the exception occured.

**-** The **line number** where the exception occured.

```
catch (SQLException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it seems to me i dont have to overcomplicate this part, because (as you and JB mention) printStackTrace tell everything.

Answer (score 0):

Why would the business layer need to know such fine-grained details? How can the business logic depend on exactly which line in your db transaction failed? This is only interesting to the human developer/maintainer. BTW I wouldn't even catch anything—I would let the exception propagate upwards to the main exception barrier, the place where you manage JDBC connections. You have transaction management repeated in every DAO method, that isn't very good either. You should let your business-level code (as well as DAO) be concerned only with the specifics of each transaction and leave the connection and transaction management to one central place. If you used Spring for your project (a very warm suggestion), this would be easy to set up.

Comment: I think the business logic must control transactions thats why i think the meaningful infos from dao can be important. Do you think any sql exception in the dao must fire transaction rollback in the business layer ?

Comment: A transaction either succeeds in full or fails in full---that's the most basic property and should never be violated. And no, it is not up to business logic to handle transactions. As far as it is concerned, the database is just an abstract, 100% reliable datastore. Transaction management is an orthogonal concern (aspect).